# Saving Files from Assets folder to device storage working only the first time! Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I developing an Android app on Android Studio.
I added a few files on Assets folder and my goal is the user through a button press to save them on his device.
I managed to find a way to do that but I have a problem!

After the first installation the app runs perfectly!
When I uninstalled it and reinstalled it the files were failing to be saved!

As you can see on my code, the folder that I am saving the files is the "/Documents".
I tried to change this location on my code and install the app again. Same results!!
It runs for the first time but when I am unistall it and reinstall it (with no changes on my code) I am getting the "Failed!" message as you can see on my code!

Do you guys have any idea what am I missing here?

Thanks!!

````
public class GKL10_pre extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button button; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gkl10_pre);




        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B_GKL10_FILES);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                copyAsset("file1.pdf");
                copyAsset("file2.pdf");
                copyAsset("file3.pdf");
                copyAsset("file4.pdf");

            }
        });
    }

    private void copyAsset(String filename){
        String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Documents";
        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        if(!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = assetManager.open(filename);
            File outFile = new File(dirPath, filename);
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            copyFile(in, out);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } finally {
            if(in != null){
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(out != null){
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }


}```
````

Comment: "Failed" is your own message. You have an IOException with a message. The message is in e.getMessage(). Toast that. The message can also be seen in logcat.

Comment: `if(!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }` That should be `if(!dir.exists()) {
            if (!dir.mkdirs()) return;
        }`.

Answer (score 0):

The copy after reinstall fails as your files are still in Document directory but are not owned by the new install. So your app has no read an write access for those files.

You blindly try to overwrite them but that will not go lacking write access.

Try File.exists(), File.canRead and File.canWrite().

Comment: I install the app for the first time. I am able to save the files. I am saving them and they are available to me through the /Documents folder on my device. Then I Unistall the app AND I delete the files from the /Documents folder. I install the app again with no changes on my code. The saving procedure is failing. Do not forget that the app is trying to save files from Assets folder of the app to /Documents folder on the device. 

If I change the destination folder from /Documents to /Download that will work from just one time again!

Comment: W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/file1.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
W/System.err:     at com.example.hcghelp.GKL10_pre.copyAsset(GKL10_pre.java:84)
W/System.err:     at com.example.hcghelp.GKL10_pre.access$000(GKL10_pre.java:28)
W/System.err:     at com.example.hcghelp.GKL10_pre$2.onClick(GKL10_pre.java:56)

Comment: W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

Comment: W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)

Comment: W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7542)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
W/System.err:  ... 17 more
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10157; state: ENABLED

Comment: my last 4 comments are containing the errors from the debug of the app.
This is only for the first file...
I do not know if that helps

Comment: Your first comment. You are only repeating yourself. You tell nothing new. You should have said: O was it that! Read my answer again.

Comment: Your second comment: The log tells you permission denied for exactly the path to your file. So no write access i told you. No permission to write.

Comment: The rest of comments have nothing to do with writing a file.

Comment: `Try File.exists(), File.canRead and File.canWrite().` And why dont i get a report?

Comment: Please explain me more about the below suggested methods. I am not able to understand the usage of them here in my problem. 

File.canread()
File.canwrite()
File.exists() 

I read about them and I found out that their purpose is to give us feedback if we can read, if we can write and if the file exists. What if I can not as it seems that I can not.? 

Also!
Important!
I have these two Iines on my manifest.
After the installation of the app there is a pop up asking for permission from user.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 

But this is not working until I go manually to app settings and give the accesses. 

I read about runntime permissions and stuff like that.. barely understand!
Can u help?

Comment: You should google for them as all has been explained here often. If you cant write to a file then display a toast to the user saying so. Further you did not tell why you want to copy to storage.

Comment: So, your commnet to my question is " google it ".
Thanks for your time my friend but this was not helpful at all. Before any of my questions here, I am trying to read and find it by myself. Unfortunately, I was not able to solve this problem. Not even with the "solutions" from here. I will keep googling. Thanks!